# Getting keyboard height from Notification

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I am getting keyboard height from Notification with code

```
  CGFloat height = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].height;
```

I use it to present some other View and it height the same as height of keyboard.
For this I create temp textField and grab from it keyboard height. I use code :

```
 UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:tempTextField];
[tempTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[tempTextField resignFirstResponder];
[tempTextField removeFromSuperview];
```

And then I get value of height. Its equal to 253. But then I get height from real textField its 216. I need to get 216 value in notification that send from temp textfield. How can I get it?

Comment: Please make yourself clear, are you trying to add a temp textfield with the same height as the keyboard to add it to your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

216 is the height of iOS built in keyboard without QuickType.
253 is with it.

So in your case you have to set autocorrectionType to no.

```
UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
tempTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:tempTextField];
[tempTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[tempTextField resignFirstResponder];
[tempTextField removeFromSuperview];
```

I don't know what you are trying to do with the height, but I cannot sure this is the best way to get the height of the keyboard.

Comment: thanks, it works. I need to get height of keyboard before my custom view is appeared to set it height as height of keyboard